# Laravel factory Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I get this error when trying to run a factory in laravel 8. I've looked though several posts about this error but they all seem to come from saving/creating directly incorrectly. Not using a factory. So I am not sure why the factory isn't saving it correctly.

My migration has:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->longText('desc');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

My model has:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($this->name);
    }
}
```

My factory has:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->words,
        'desc' => $this->faker->sentence,
        'user_id' => rand(1,10)
    ];
}
```

And my Posts seeder has:

```
public function run()
{
    Post::factory()->times(13)->create();
}
```

My main DatabaseSeeder runs a user seeder that seeds 10 users. Then a post seeder to seed 13 posts.

I run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` and it fails when it gets to the Post Seeder with this error:

> TypeError
>
> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize()
> must be of the type array, string given, called in
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php
> on line 886
>
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php:136
> 132▕      *
> 133▕      * @param  array  $values
> 134▕      * @return string
> 135▕      */   ➜ 136▕     public function parameterize(array $values)
> 137▕     {
> 138▕         return implode(', ', array_map([$this, 'parameter'], $values));
> 139▕     }
> 140▕
>
> ```
>   +1 vendor frames    2   [internal]:0
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar::Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\{closure}("Odio
> ```
>
> voluptatem quis facere possimus ut.", "desc")
>
> ```
>   +13 vendor frames    16  database/seeders/PostsSeeder.php:17
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::create()
> ```

I'm really not understanding why its expecting an array for a string column.

Comment: this was for the faker package but same issue. [Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515566/type-error-argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-database-grammarparameterize-mus)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`'name' => $this->faker->words` will return an array of words.

You can either call the underlying method and tell it to return a string by passing true as the 2nd argument:

```
$this->faker->words(3, true) // 3 is the number of words which is the default
```

or you could use something like `sentence`

```
$this->faker->sentence
```

[words() documentation](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/text-and-paragraphs/#words)

Comment: Ah it threw me off that the error mentioned the next field "desc" but I suppose by now I should be used to PHP errors and how the real problem is usually on the line before. I had even tried the method instead of property too but I didn't know about the second boolean parameter.